# Prevent a google sheets IF(TODAY()) function from editing after a certain date

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to build a google sheets cell that updates after a certain date.

The function I'm using is `=if(today()=oct 4, count(A:A))` which will just count rows. The only issue I'm encountering is that the `A:A` column updates regularly and I want it to just be static.

Ideally on october 4th the `A:A` column would be counted and it just get turned into a static value.

Not sure if a complete apps script would be the better option.

Comment: Use and time based trigger and a function.

Comment: Have you tried using apps script as mentioned on the previous comment and the answer?

Answer (score 0):

Since you cannot automatically fix values using a formula, you need to use apps script. Ideally use an apps script which contains a trigger depending on your needs, as I assume that you do not only have a single instance where you want to fix the values from the formula. If you are clear about what you want to achieve then the community can help you. And we always appreciate if you've tried doing t yourself in order to see your effort.